# Why do I see scrabbled output when using JSch?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ssh, jsch

I am trying to use `JSch`. I tried the example [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html)
Although I can connect the output is weird.
I get the following:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 31 19:44:25 2013 from 10.2.251.77

[1mcli:~ # [m
```

And if I do e.g. an `ls` I get:

```
[0m[01;34m.InstallAnywhere[0m  [00m.bash_history                [00m.bash_profile[0m       
[01;34mbin[0m                             [00msles11-patched[0m  
[01;34m.kbd[0m              [00mindex.html[0m                      [00mtest.sql[0m  
[00m.viminfo[0m          [00;31mipvsadm-1.26-1.src.rpm[0m  
[m[1mcli:~ # [m
```

These are the directory contents but why are they displayed like that?
I am running in this from Eclipse and this is what I see in Eclipse output. If I run this from Windows `CMD` it stucks

**Update:**
I noticed that if I connect to a different linux the output is fine!
Only if I connect to a specific linux installation I see these weird characters! Any idea what is causing this?

**Update2:**
Following the link of @PeterMmm I did `printf "äöü" | xxd`. Both the "bad" and good one give:
`0000000: e4f6 fc`
I also did `locale`.
In the "bad" case:

```
# locale  
LANG=POSIX  
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8  
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"  
LC_TIME="POSIX"  
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"  
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"  
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"  
LC_PAPER="POSIX"  
LC_NAME="POSIX"  
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"  
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"  
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"  
LC_ALL=
```

In the good system:

```
LANG=POSIX  
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8  
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"  
LC_TIME="POSIX"  
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"  
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"  
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"   
LC_PAPER="POSIX"  
LC_NAME="POSIX"  
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"   
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"   
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"   
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"  
LC_ALL=
```

Configuration seems to be the same. So what could be causing this?

Comment: Charcter encoding of the terminal session [read further here](http://benjamin-schweizer.de/unix-terminals-surviving-the-encoding-hell.html).

Comment: Here is a solution:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830620/getting-strange-output-from-the-remote-shell-in-jsch

Have fun :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check 
[Funny Shell Output: [01;32mtestfile.txt[00m instead of testfile.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221127/funny-shell-output-0132mtestfile-txt00m-instead-of-testfile-txt)

```
((ChannelShell) channel).setPtyType("dumb");
```

Does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

They are escape sequences for the terminal emulation.  I guess that there is no relation to the character encoding.

**Update:**
If ChannelShell#setPty(false) is invoked, a pseudo-terminal will not be allocated and escape sequences will not be appeared.

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
((ChannelShell)channel).setPty(false);                  // !!
...
channel.connect();
```

Comment: I added `((ChannelShell)channel).setPty(false);` and I don't get a prompt.It seems like I can not provide input to the program

Comment: Yes, you don't get a prompt, but you must be able to provide input to the program.